# ContextMenu not appearing for a Listview

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity in which the list has been registered for contextmenu.But the context menu not appearing on the emulator after long press on any of the list items.To further inspect the problem,I have added a LOg.i() statement which has been placed inside the method onContextItemSelected.The code snippets has been provided below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<Item
    android:id="@+id/details_context_button"
    android:title="Details"
    /> 
<Item
    android:id="@+id/edit_context_button"
    android:title="Edit"
    />
 <Item
    android:id="@+id/delete_context_button"
    android:title="Delete"
    />

</menu>`
```

IN THE LISTACTIVITY ONCREATE METHOD:

```
 ListView list=getListView();       
this.setListAdapter(new NamesAdapter   
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, index_ids));
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

THE ONCONTEXT ITEM SELECTED METHOD GIVEN BELOW:

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenuInfo info){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,info);
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_items_contextmenu, menu); 
        Log.i("","m here");     
    }
```

the logcat shows the "m here" line.But no contextmenu appears.I am very much puzzled.Can somebody please help?

Comment: You might change `Item` to `item` in your menu xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation but I just tested it. The `<item>` tag, as I suspected, is case sensitive. So change all of your tags in your menu's xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item
          android:id="@+id/details_context_button"
          android:title="Details"/> 
      <item
          android:id="@+id/edit_context_button"
          android:title="Edit"/>
      <item
          android:id="@+id/delete_context_button"
          android:title="Delete"/>
   </menu>
```

Your menu won't show up if `<item>` is upper case

According to [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)

> XML Tags are Case Sensitive
>   XML tags are case sensitive...
>
> Opening and closing tags must be written with the same case:

Comment: yup.You are 100% correct.I wonder why during coding eclipse dint throw any warning.Anyway,thanks a lot.

Comment: Because its not illegal and from what I understand there are workarounds to make it case insensitive but probably not a good idea. So, while xml is case-sensitive, the tags aren't illegal if they're the wrong case but they won't give the desired results

Answer (score 0):

I think listview is intercepting events here and hence your activity is not receiving it.I am not sure but it looks like this .